# error calling a function from main

Tags: c++

I am trying to call two functions from one main function the code of my main func is as follows:

```
#include <watchdoggen.h>
#include <concat.h>
using namespace std;


int main () {
    string plain;
    char key1[16];
    char si[10];
    char w[10];
    char fid[20];

    cout << "Enter the number of splits: ";
    cin >> si;
    cout << "Enter the number of watchdogs: ";
    cin >> w;
    cout << "Enter the Fid: ";
    cin >> fid;
    concat(si, w, fid);
    //cout<<"\nThe plain txt is: "<< si <<endl;
    plain = si;
    cout << "the plaintext is: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, plain);
    cout << "Enter the Master Key: ";
    cin>>key1;
    byte* key_s = (byte*)key1;
    cout << "key: " << plain << endl;
    watchdoggen(plain,key_s);
}
```

Here I am trying to basically give the output of one function as the input of the other function.
When I compile the code, I get the following error:

```
test4watchdoggen.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test4watchdoggen.cpp:67:19: error: ‘concat’ was not declared in this scope
```

I am using the following command to compile :

```
g++ -g3 -ggdb -O0 -DDEBUG -I/usr/include/cryptopp test4watchdoggen.cpp \
    watchdoggen.cpp concat.cpp -o test4watchdog -lcryptopp -lpthread
```

Need some help on this.

concat.h

```
#ifndef TRY_H_INCLUDED
#define TRY_H_INCLUDED

char concat(char si[],char w[],char fid[]);

#endif
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. What's in the `<concat.h>` header?  AFAIK, it isn't a standard header, but its name suggests that's where your `concat()` function might be supposed to come from.  From your code, it is not clear where `concat()` would place the output, if it was declared.

Comment: You have a combination of things that sound similar but are different and will give you a lot of problems when used together. Why not use either char[] or string, but not both?

Comment: Have a look inside the `<concat>` header... check that the `concat()` function you're attempting to call is there, that there are no `#if` statements that might be removing it from the translation unit, and whether it's in a namespace that you'll need to use to call it.  (Alternatively - and sometimes better - you can invoke the compiler `g++ -E -DDEBUG -I/usr/include/cryptopp test4watchdoggen.cpp     watchdoggen.cpp concat.cpp` and inspect the post-preprocessing code to ensure the function's there as expected).

Comment: #ifndef TRY_H_INCLUDED
      #define TRY_H_INCLUDED

      char concat(char si[],char w[],char fid[]);


     #endif                                                                                       this is what my concat.h looks like

Comment: Does your `watchdoggen.h` also have `#define TRY_H_INCLUDED` in it?

Comment: #ifndef TRY_H_INCLUDED
#define TRY_H_INCLUDED

char watchdoggen (std::string plain,byte* key_s);


#endif                                                                                                     this is the content of my watchdoggen.h

Comment: when i run the two functions separately they work fine, but when i put it under one main func i get the error.

Comment: Change all the TRY_H_INCLUDED in concat.h to CONCAT_H_INCLUDED and try again.

Answer (score 2):

The [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) is used to prevent including the same header twice:

```
#ifndef MY_GUARD
#define MY_GUARD
// code ...
#endif
```

But this only works correctly if each header has a unique name for the guard.  In your case, the guards in both of your headers have the same name `TRY_H_INCLUDED`, so including one automatically prevents the other from being included.

The fix is to simply give each header file a unique name for the include guard as Hari Mahadevan suggested.